# Get URL of Post You Are Editing

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks

I can't seem to find this anywhere,
Is there a way to retrieve the URL of the post (which is of a custom post type) you are editing. Basically I want to somehow get the same URL that shows up like this:
Permalink: (link to post)
on the edit screen.

Comment: Did you mean add the link in the admin panel for editing posts? There should be a view post link there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the `$post` variable (you may need `global $post;`) from which you can get the post ID (`$post->ID`). Then `$perm = get_permalink( $post->ID );` should give you what you want.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink